# GParted stuck when formatting swap drive

Tags: ubuntu, gparted, parted

I'm trying to format a USB disk which was used as a swap drive on another machine using `gparted`. It keeps getting stuck at the following screen

[image]

`iotop -o` shows no IO activity. It freezes only when formatting this particular drive. I've tried 2 other sticks and `gparted` did fine. Anyone know how this can be fixed?

EDIT:

Here's the output of `dmesg`:

```
[  352.763146] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  352.912386] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[  352.912387] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  352.912389] usb 1-3: Product: Flash Drive
[  352.912389] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Samsung
[  352.912390] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 0344818020002557
[  352.917347] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  352.917542] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[  354.102796] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  Flash Drive      1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  354.103526] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  354.106521] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 62668800 512-byte logical blocks: (32.1 GB/29.9 GiB)
[  354.108598] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  354.108600] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  354.109538] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  354.126159] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[16870.669971] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[17038.471436] INFO: task scsi_eh_8:3326 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[17038.471440]       Tainted: P           OE   4.13.0-46-generic #51-Ubuntu
[17038.471440] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[17038.471442] scsi_eh_8       D    0  3326      2 0x80000000
[17038.471443] Call Trace:
[17038.471460]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[17038.471461]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[17038.471462]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
[17038.471463]  __mutex_lock.isra.2+0x18c/0x4d0
[17038.471465]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[17038.471466]  ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
[17038.471467]  mutex_lock+0x2f/0x40
[17038.471472]  device_reset+0x22/0x50 [usb_storage]
[17038.471478]  scsi_eh_ready_devs+0x333/0xbf0
[17038.471481]  ? __pm_runtime_resume+0x5b/0x80
[17038.471483]  ? scsi_try_target_reset+0x90/0x90
[17038.471484]  scsi_error_handler+0x4c3/0x5b0
[17038.471489]  kthread+0x128/0x140
[17038.471491]  ? scsi_eh_get_sense+0x200/0x200
[17038.471492]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
[17038.471493]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[17038.471496] INFO: task gpartedbin:29528 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[17038.471498]       Tainted: P           OE   4.13.0-46-generic #51-Ubuntu
[17038.471499] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[17038.471500] gpartedbin      D    0 29528  29523 0x00000000
[17038.471501] Call Trace:
[17038.471502]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
[17038.471506]  ? blk_finish_plug+0x2c/0x40
[17038.471507]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
[17038.471510]  io_schedule+0x16/0x40
[17038.471514]  wait_on_page_bit_common+0xd8/0x160
[17038.471515]  ? page_cache_tree_insert+0xc0/0xc0
[17038.471516]  __filemap_fdatawait_range+0xfe/0x160
[17038.471517]  file_write_and_wait_range+0x60/0xc0
[17038.471521]  blkdev_fsync+0x1b/0x50
[17038.471523]  vfs_fsync_range+0x4e/0xb0
[17038.471524]  do_fsync+0x3d/0x70
[17038.471526]  SyS_fsync+0x10/0x20
[17038.471527]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x24/0xab
[17038.471528] RIP: 0033:0x7f624e231490
[17038.471529] RSP: 002b:00007ffce924b1c0 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000004a
[17038.471530] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000558e5fbd3f20 RCX: 00007f624e231490
[17038.471530] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000558e5fc0e330 RDI: 0000000000000006
[17038.471531] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000558e5fc63d40 R09: 0000000000000000
[17038.471531] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000010
[17038.471532] R13: 0000558e5f96c7a0 R14: 0000558e5f96c790 R15: 0000000000000000
```

`smartctl` gives the following:

```
$ sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb -d sat -T permissive
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.13.0-46-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     [No Information Found]
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Fri Apr 26 12:57:58 2019 AEST
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

Comment: What does the “Details” section show?

Comment: @StephenKitt It can't be expanded because it's frozen.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use a usb drive for swap - can you test the USB drive, it might be damaged. Then again, I do not think that swap in this day and age is useful, worse, what is the point to swap to a sloooow usb drive ? Can you open a terminal and issue `dmesg` ? We should see any IO errors, there ...

Comment: @thecarpy I understand that. I'm just using this as swap for a raspberry pi. I've pasted output of `dmesg` in my question now.

Answer (score 1):

Use different software that gives you a better view.

In the lines below starting with `#` means running as `root`
First, check this is the correct disk !!!IMPORTANT!!! If you lose all data because of these instructions, you are on your own. I'd use `testdisk` or `photorec` to recover what I can.

```
# parted /dev/sdb
Model: Some disk model
Disk: /dev/sdb : 29.9GB
Sector Size: 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags
```

Create a partition table and swap partition

```
# parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt #!!!ACHTUNG! This will erase ALL partitions on disk /dev/sdb!!!
# parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary linux-swap 512B 29.9GB
# parted print
Model: Some disk model
Disk: /dev/sdb : 29.9GB
Sector Size: 512B/4096B
Partition Table: mbr
Disk Flags
Number    Start    End    Size    File System    Name    Flags
 1        512B     29.9Gb 29.9Gb                 primary
```

Format the partition for swap

```
# mkswap /dev/sdb1
```

If it fails, you're more likely to see the reason why. But from the look of your `dmesg` output, it looks like you have a corrupt device.

You should consider using `smartctl` to check the SMART status of your drive. To install, you need smartmontools (debian, ubuntu, mint, devuan ...)

Comment: I get `mkswap: /dev/sdb: warning: don't erase bootbits sectors
        (gpt partition table detected). Use -f to force.
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 29.9 GiB (32086421504 bytes)
no label, UUID=3d13f2a8-a754-4377-bac6-a361594a60f7` I suppose it worked?

Comment: You see that message because you should use a swap `partition` not the whole drive.

Comment: @thecarpy `mkswap /dev/sdb1` gives `cannot open /dev/sdb1: No such file or directory`. It seems to "work" on `/dev/sdb` though. I've also added the output from `smartctl`. This is a USB stick, so I'm not sure if it supports SMART.